# Any native ZIP/Packaging for .NET3.5

Tags: .net, zip

I am looking for Zip/Unzip operation in my .NET application. I can see plenty of third party implementations, But is there one part of .NET framework?

Or let me tell you what exactly I am looking for. I may just need to package a folder and need to give a particular extension to it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[System.IO.Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx)

Comment: Darn... That library was just on the tip of my tongue and you beat me to it!

Comment: The interface can be used to produce a zip file, but it's a pretty complicated programming model, and it's oriented toward making "packages", not generic zip files.

Answer (score 0):

The J# library (no longer supported) includes zip/unzip routines.  Be careful with gzip as it is a single-file compression stream and has no concept of files or directories.  Some folks have reported (limited) success with the cabarc tools but they're not .NET.

Comment: Don't use J#.  Out of support, a huge runtime, buggy.